# Adding images from assets folder in adapter

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I'm trying to display images from assets folder. I have this error:
 [image]

```
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFormatAssets(product.getProductId());
```

try { Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(product.getProductId()); imageView.setImageResource(bitmap);

Comment: Is that any particular reason you are not using drawable folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be `setImageBitmap(bitmap)` not `setImageResource(bitmap)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `imageView.setImageResource(bitmap)` try to use `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` directly.

Answer (score 1):

when you want to set a bitmap image to a image view don't use `setImageResource(bitmap)`

**use** `setImageBitmap(bitmap)` as below

**setImageBitmap(bitmap)** Sets a Bitmap as the content of this ImageView.
like this

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

get your bitmap from assets using below code

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Your Welcome @AmmArYasser

Answer (score 1):

following are used for getting the image from asset folder and set it to `ImageView`.

```
// load image
try {
    // get input stream
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("avatar.jpg");
    // load image as Drawable
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
    // set image to ImageView
    mImage.setImageDrawable(d);
}
catch(IOException ex) {
    return;
}
```